# Create Android APK Test Application

Tags: android, testing, apk, robotium

I have an app to be tested, called app A.

I also have a test project for automated testing of this app.

I want to have a second app which includes these test cases, so that I can run all test cases for app A by starting another, app B.
I don't want to start tests in Eclipse, I want to start them directly from the phone where the app should be tested

Someone knows a solution?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to run the tests from your code, in such case this **[post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/09/android-testing-running-tests-from-code.html)**, presenting a solution to run instrumentation from code, will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didnt' understand... You want to start an activity from MainActivity but the 2nd activity has to be hidden from launcher?

Comment: I want to test an activity by starting a test application on the device.

Comment: I don't know what it is but there is a "project" called Android Application Test if you click on the button of create new project

Comment: There's an app to test. For this app there's a test project. I want to deploy that test project on the device that I can start the test project directly from the device to test the app